# ‘ant’ is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, ant, path

I have the same issue as this user: [ant - not recognized as an internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587172/ant-not-recognized-as-an-internal)

however unfortunately none of the solutions have worked for me in that post or any other. I've also looked at other commands not recognized and specifically adding a path variable. The procedure I am using is as follows:

```
Extract to a desired installation directory, e.g. C:\apache-ant
Create an ANT_HOME environment variable`

Open System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables
Create a new system variable
    Variable name: ANT_HOME
    Variable value: C:\apache-ant 

Add %ANT_HOME%\bin directory to the PATH system variable

Open System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables
Under system variables, select PATH and append ;%ANT_HOME%\bin
    e.g. %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin

Verify that ANT is installed.

Open a new command window and type:
C:\>ant -v`
```

In my case the Variable value is `C:\apache-ant\apache-ant-1.8.2`.

My exact path variable is `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin` which doesn't have any spaces between semicolons.

However testing the ant installation does not work, the picture below is what I'm experiencing:

[image]

I have tried restarting on numerous occasions to no avail. I have run out of ideas, so if anyone has any any information would be helpful. Thanks!

### EDIT

Posted results of dir:

[image]

Comment: Do "echo %PATH%" and make sure "c:\apache-ant\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin" is in there. By the way the correct way to view the ant version is ant -version.

Comment: C:\Users\Development Admin>echo %PATH%  
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin;C:\Windows\
System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\
jdk1.6.0_29\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin

Comment: ANT_HOME is not being resolved. Change "%ANT_HOME%\bin" in the Path system environment variable to "c:\apache-ant\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin".

Comment: WORKS!, wow thank you very much. Being a tad new here, how would I "accept this answer" and give you a well deserved upvote?

Comment: You're welcome. I copied my comment and added it as an answer. You can accept the answer now as the right one.

Comment: I also created environment variables correctly, but ant was still not recognized. Funny thing, I just relaunched command prompt.

Comment: @AdamBruss' solution also did the trick for me :) ofc don't forget to restart the command prompt.

complete set of Power Shell commands:

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231", "User")

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "C:\apache-ant-1.9.14\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin", "User")

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`ANT_HOME` is not being resolved. Change `%ANT_HOME%\bin` in the Path system environment variable to `c:\apache-ant\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin`.

Comment: See Joshua's comment below for a possible reason.

Comment: it shows that 'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Comment: My issue was resolved just after adding to PATH system variable c:\apache-ant\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin. Earlier bin was not in path.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue, but the reason that `%ANT_HOME%` wasn't resolving is that I had added it as a USER variable, not a SYSTEM one. Sorted now, thanks to this post.

Comment: I had this same issue.  I don't recall seeing it with other versions, but I had it with ANT version 1.8.2.  Thank you!

Comment: This solved the issue for me for ANT version 1.9.4. Logging in and out had no effect. Once I changed the user variable to a system variable the `ant` command worked without having to relog.

Answer (score 6):

create a script including the following;
(replace the ant and jdk paths with whatever is correct for your machine)

```
set  PATH=%BASEPATH%
set ANT_HOME=c:\tools\apache-ant-1.9-bin
set JAVA_HOME=c:\tools\jdk7x64
set PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

run it in shell.

Answer (score 4):

When Environment variables are changed log off and log in again so that it will be applied.

Comment: This did not work for me. After changing `%ANT_HOME%` from a user variable to a system variable, the `ant` command worked at the command line without having to relog.

Comment: a restart fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded ant (http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi), unzipped to my C drive, and used the windows 'doskey' command:

```
doskey ant=C:\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin\ant.bat $*
```

this will work as long as you use the same command console, to make it permanent is more difficult: http://darkforge.blogspot.com/2010/08/permanent-windows-command-line-aliases.html

Answer (score 2):

Please follow these steps

1. In User Variables

   > Set **VARIABLE NAME**=ANT_HOME  **VARIABLE PATH** =C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.7

2.Edit **User Variable** PATH = %ANT_HOME%\bin

3. Go to **System Variables**

   - Set **Path** =%ANT_HOME%\bin

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. The solution is to add a `\` at the end of `%ANT_HOME%\bin` so it became `%ANT_HOME%\bin\`

Worked for me. (Should be system var)

Answer (score 0):

even with the environment variables set, I found that `ant -version` does not work in scripts.  Try `call ant -version`

Answer (score 0):

Need to see whether you got ant folder moved by mistake or unknowingly.
It is set in environment variables.I resolved this once as mentioned below.

I removed ant folder by mistake and placed in another folder.I went to command prompt and typed "path". It has given me path as "F:\apache-ant-1.9.4\". 
So I moved the ant back to F drive and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If none above helped anyone...My issue was that I was trying to use `ant -version` on a cmd prompt that I had already opened before I added `apache-ant` to the path.

As the cmd prompt was using the `PATH` it had when it was opened and not the new one (that had `apache-ant`) it wasn't finding it.

Opening a new cmd and running `ant -version` showed me I actually did have it installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem , what I did for fix :

1. Open system environment variable
2. Click on environment variable
3. in user varaible -> edit path and then add C:\FolderWhereYouInstalled\ant\ant_1.8.4\bin
4. Click ok
5. Open cmd and type : ant -version

thanks, might help someone :)