# node is not recognized as an internal or external command but is in PATH

Tags: node.js

Although I've follow suggestions from:

- ['node' is not recognized as an internal or an external command, operable program or batch file while using phonegap/cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412938/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-an-external-command-operable-program)
- [Node.js doesn't recognize system path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768549/node-js-doesnt-recognize-system-path)
- [‘ant’ is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262712/ant-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)...

I'm having an strange issue: Resume, although node path is list in Path, it doesn't find node.

Workflow:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]    //Running CMD on windows 8.1 
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

I followed suggestions in SO, adding variable to Environment Variables, and it's display Ok in Path:

```
C:\Users\myUser>path
PATH=c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs ; (...omitted...) //So folder is there
```

Next line will fail

```
C:\Users\myUser>call jasmine-node spec  
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\myUser>cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs" //So I move to the folder list before...
```

But if I move to folder list in Path, then it works OK.

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs>call jasmine-node spec
>  (...omitted...) //Exec OK.

c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs>node
>   //Exec OK. Waiting...
```

It seems contradictory.

Comment: Is there really a space before the semicolon in your `PATH` or did you add that while redacting?

Comment: O_O hobbs!! That was it! I edit manually adding a whitespace! Thanks a lot! I've spent hours trying to find the problem! If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: This happened to me **JUST AFTER** I installed a different, non related program. It might not be anything Node related that causes this problem to "suddenly" crop up. In my case, Dropbox altered my PATH.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nodejs directory in your `PATH` isn't recognized because there's a space before the semicolon, so Windows is looking for a directory with a space at the end of the name, which doesn't exist.

Comment: In my case the `%path%` was placed before the node path.

Answer (score 5):

**Error: 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command**

The problem is may be the node is not installed on the machine in which the application is running.

Then install it and set the environment variable for nodejs.

**Or**

One more reason can be the nodejs path not set in the environment variable.

Check with the following - 
open Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> Path

the nodejs path should be available here.
If not available then add the following:

C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs
OR
C:\Program Files\nodejs

Now Re-Run the application and the Error got resolved.

Answer (score 3):

;C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Slash after \nodejs\ worked for me

Answer (score 3):

> Usually the environment variables are not effective till a system
>   Restart.

I suggest a `System Restart` for all those  who face the same issue when doing a clean install.

This worked for me.

Comment: On contrary, USUAL behavior is that system restart is NOT required But NEW command window has ALWAYS to be opened for the cmd to work.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, you need to set node.js folder path into system variables or user variables.

1) open Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables

2) in "User variables" or "System variables" find variable `PATH` and add node.js folder path as value. Usually it is `C:\Program Files\nodejs;`. If variable doesn't exists, create it.

3) Restart your IDE or computer.

It is useful add also "npm" and "Git" paths as variable, separated by semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

If you did `npm install jasmine-node -g` you should just need to do `jasmine-node spec` (no `call` prefix).

Comment: Thanks mscdex, I did a global install. Anyway, if I remove the 'call' prefix I still receive the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you've checked your `PATH`, and are sure that the path for `node` is added properly, then you're likely to face the problem while running `node` OR `npm` commands with CLI's other than the default command line interface of the operating system (e.g. Git bash in Windows).

The strange part is that you can check for `node -v` and `npm -v` in those CLIs, but for some reasons, they don't work well with those commands (especially when combined with `install` or `update`).

## Possible Solution

Try running `node` with the default terminal for your OS.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue even after adding node.exe to PATH. I wasn't able to run node command at random locations without running command prompt as administrator.

Solution to this issue is, you have to give full access permissions to this node.exe file for different user types. open the properties of node.exe, go to security tabs, check all the security options to the user on your local machine.

after doing this you should be able to access the node.exe file from any location.

Answer (score 0):

things to check:

open CMD>Go to the directory where node.exe resides > type node -v > :

1. if it shows the version: Please add the same path  (like> 
   `PATH=C:\Programfiles\nodejs\;`) in the OS path in environment variable (any of the 
   system or user variable, both work fine)
2. if it doesn't recognize, please add a variable `PATHEXT=.exe;` in the environment 
   variable (The PathExt is an Environment Variable that stores a list of the file 
   extensions for the operation system to execute) and save them.

   Now open a new command prompt window and check.it must work.

Answer (score 0):

After installing nodejs you have to restart your terminal or IDE .

Answer (score 0):

> C:\Program Files\nodejs

adding the path without the semi-colon did it for me...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For the issue which is coming "node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.", I have tried updating the path, but the issue didn't resolve. So I uninstalled and installed node.js and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

The error:

> node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

And the following solution:

1. Set Environment variable `NODE_HOME` as `C:\Program Files\nodejs`
2. Open cmd window and run:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
npm install connect
npm install -g appium
```

Comment: Hi, Sanchi, and welcome to SO. Installing new packages is not a solution.

Answer (score -3):

It's as simple as adding the location of nodejs (`C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs`) to your `PATH` variable and restarting your application with "Run as administrator".

Comment: Can you please brief it