# NPM run scripts aren't able to call `node`

Tags: node.js, npm

**Quick Summary**

This is not a duplicate of the linked question, the issue there was a typo, this isn't isn't a typo.

I can run `node` in my bash terminal fine. If I try and run `node` inside an NPM script in that same bash terminal, then I get the error `'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

**Original Question**

I'm having issues running `npm install` in one of my projects currently, but to be able to simplify all of the moving parts, I've created an NPM script in my `package.json` file, simply calling `node nodetest.js`.

The content of `nodetest.js` is as follows:

```
console.log('Node Test Success!');
```

On the command line, I can call `node nodetest.js`, and it will output the console log as expected.

If I call `npm run nodetest`, I get the error saying `'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Inside the same command line, I have access to `node` (`/c/Program Files/nodejs/node`), `npm` (`/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm`), and even `npx` (`/c/Program Files/nodejs/npx`)

Node is set in my PATH variable, and I've even added it to `.bashrc`.

What else could possibly be the problem?

**Edit**: I neglected to detail my system

- Windows 10
- Using Git Bash inside ConEmu
- Node version 10.1.0
- NPM version 6.0.0

**Edit 2**: Some further curiosities

If I change my NPM script to be `"nodetest": "\"/c/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe\" nodetest.js"`, and then run `npm run nodetest`, I get an error in the output:

```
> "/c/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe" nodetest.js

The system cannot find the path specified.
```

BUT, if I copy that command exactly, and run it directly on the command line, it will work perfectly!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node is not recognized as an internal or external command but is in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144724/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-but-is-in-path)

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions in that thread. I've been doing a lot of searching before finally deciding to post a question myself