# Ant isn't being recognized as a command. Ant 1.7.1

Tags: java, ant

I been doing everything I can to get this resolved. Although I cannot seem to figure this out.

First I want to share what I have read and tried:

I read this post: [‘ant’ is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262712/ant-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command#)

I also read the documentation: [ant.apache.org/manual/install.html](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html)

Although "ant" is still not recognizing as a command.

Here is a screenshot of ANT_HOME:

[image]

[image]

My path is:

```
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Client\win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access\Emulator;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fa;%ANT_HOME%\bin;
```

C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Client\win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access\Emulator;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fa;%ANT_HOME%\bin;

Everything seems to be correct. Although I cannot figure out the issue why its not running as a command. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more digging and I found out that I had to add %ANT_HOME%/bin to my **System Path** not the **User Path**. Plus windows hates using long paths for ant for some reason. It now works perfectly.

I found a great article if anyone gets stuck, on their build.

[Ant Installation - Web Tutorial](http://www.michael-thomas.com/tech/apache/ant/tutorial_install_ant/)

Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 1):

`%ANT_HOME%` is supposed to be the folder where ANT is located, so that should be `c:\apache-ant-1.7.1` without the `bin` directory. Your path is pointing to `%ANT_HOME%\bin` which seems correct under normal circumstances, but it doesn't work current because effectively in your case it points to `c:\apache-ant-1.7.1\bin\bin`...

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I made the changes. I am still getting no recognized. Does JAVA_HOME affects ant in anyway?