# Android Hello World ant debug

Tags: android

Forgive me for what is undoubtedly a dumb question.

The hello world lesson (developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html) suggests you change directories to the root of your android project and execute "ant debug". This is what I get;

```
C:\Users\Paul\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstApp>ant debug
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Paul\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstApp>path
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\OracleClient32\Paul\product\12.1.0\c
lient_1\bin;C:\Oracledb\Paul\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\
Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

C:\Users\Paul\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstApp>
```

Comment: First download 'Ant' and then try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587172/ant-not-recognized-as-an-internal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to install Ant for windows and then make sure the ant binary is in your path. See more details here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html

Comment: done & ty. Now I get this though; 

C:\Users\Paul\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstApp>ant debug
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed               
I don't see any build.xml in my project directory

Comment: I went and looked at the link you posted in your original comment to better understand the context of the ant command. However I dont see any instructions there to use ant. Android Studio is recommending to use the gradle build system, and if you are learning how to use Android Studio etc I would recommend you go with Gradle. I used to build Android on eclipse and I can tell you that Android Studio and Gradle is far better ;-). Good Luck!